# translate my entire website from Spanish to English, , Google Translate it's no longer available

Tags: asp.net, translation

Good evening, I need help with translating my website from Spanish to English, it is developed in asp.net, my boss requested that I use google translate for ease, but the google translation service seems to be no longer available. Anyone know of a similar library that does the same, that does the automatic translation of my entire website

Google translate sends me this message:

We no longer provide new access to Google Translate's Website Translator. This change does not affect existing use of the Website Translator.
We encourage users looking to translate webpages to use browsers that support translation natively.

Comment: I believe that set of APIs are being deprecated in favor of their new Cloud APIs. https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/samples In that case, Azure has similar tools as well.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use the deepl API. https://www.deepl.com/de/docs-api/

There are many others that are worth looking at.

Answer (score -1):

> First, add this where you want a button to change the language in HTML body.

```
<div id='google_translate_element'/>
```

> Then add these scripts in your `<head>` tag of HTML.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function googleTranslateFunction(){
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage:'hi', layout:google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE},'google_translate_element');
} </script>
 
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
(function(){var gtConstEvalStartTime = new Date();/*

    Copyright The Closure Library Authors.
    SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
   */
   var h=this||self,l=/^[\w+/_-]+[=]{0,2}$/,m=null;
    function n(a){
       return(a=a.querySelector&&a.querySelector("script[nonce]"))&&(a=a.nonce||a.getAttribute("nonce"))&&l.test(a)?a:""
    }
    function p(a,b){
       function c(){}c.prototype=b.prototype;
       a.i=b.prototype;a.prototype=new c;
       a.prototype.constructor=a;
       a.h=function(g,f,k){
           for(var e=Array(arguments.length-2),d=2;
           d<arguments.length;d++)e[d-2]=arguments[d];
           return b.prototype[f].apply(g,e)
        }
    }
    function q(a){return a};
    function r(a){
        if(Error.captureStackTrace);
        else{var b=Error().stack;b&&(this.stack=b)}a&&(this.message=String(a))
    }

    r.prototype.name="CustomError";
    function u(a,b){
        a=a.split("%s");
        for(var c="",g=a.length-1,f=0;
        f<g;f++)c+=a[f]+(f<b.length?b[f]:"%s");
        r.call(this,c+a[g])
    }
    p(u,r);
    u.prototype.name="AssertionError";
   function v(a,b){
       throw new u("Failure"+(a?": "+a:""),Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1));
    };
    var w;
    function x(a,b){this.g=b===y?a:""}x.prototype.toString=function(){return this.g+""};var y={};
   function z(a){
       var b=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];b||(b=document.body.parentNode.appendChild(document.createElement("head")));
       b.appendChild(a)
    }
   function _loadJs(a){
       var b=document;
       var c="SCRIPT";"application/xhtml+xml"===b.contentType&&(c=c.toLowerCase());
       c=b.createElement(c);
       c.type="text/javascript";
       c.charset="UTF-8";
       if(void 0===w){b=null;var g=h.trustedTypes;
        if(g&&g.createPolicy){
            try{b=g.createPolicy("goog#html",{createScriptURL:q})}
            catch(t){h.console&&h.console.error(t.message)}w=b}
            else w=b
        }
        a=(b=w)?b.createScriptURL(a):a;a=new x(a,y);a:{
            try{
                var f=c&&c.ownerDocument,k=f&&(f.defaultView||f.parentWindow);k=k||h;
                if(k.Element&&k.Location){var e=k;break a}}
                catch(t){}e=null}
                if(e&&"undefined"!=typeof e.HTMLScriptElement&&(!c||!(c instanceof e.HTMLScriptElement)&&(c instanceof e.Location||c instanceof e.Element))){
                    e=typeof c;
                    if("object"==e&&null!=c||"function"==e)
                    try{}
                    catch(t){}
                    else d=void 0===c?"undefined":null===c?"null":typeof c;v()
                }
                a instanceof x&&a.constructor===x?d=a.g:(d=typeof a,v("expected object of type TrustedResourceUrl, got '"+a+"' of type "+("object"!=d?d:a?Array.isArray(a)?"array":d:"null")),d="type_error:TrustedResourceUrl");c.src=d;
                (d=c.ownerDocument&&c.ownerDocument.defaultView)&&d!=h?d=n(d.document):(null===m&&(m=n(h.document)),d=m);
                d&&c.setAttribute("nonce",d);z(c)
    }
   function _loadCss(a){
       var b=document.createElement("link");
       b.type="text/css";b.rel="stylesheet";
       b.charset="UTF-8";b.href=a;z(b)
    }
    function _isNS(a){
        a=a.split(".");
        for(var b=window,c=0;c<a.length;++c)if(!(b=b[a]))return!1;
        return!0
    }
   function _setupNS(a){
       a=a.split(".");
       for(var b=window,c=0;c<a.length;++c)b.hasOwnProperty?b.hasOwnProperty(a)?b=b[a]:b=b[a[c]]={}:b=b[a]||(b[a]={});
       return b
    }
   
   
   
   if (_isNS('google.translate.Element')){return}(function(){
       var c=_setupNS('google.translate._const');
       c._cest = gtConstEvalStartTime;gtConstEvalStartTime = undefined;c._cl='en';
       c._cuc='googleTranslateFunction';
       c._cac='';c._cam='';c._ctkk='447972.1887378764';
   var h='translate.googleapis.com';
   var s=(true?'https':window.location.protocol=='https:'?'https':'http')+'://';
   var b=s+h;c._pah=h;c._pas=s;c._pbi=b+'/translate_static/img/te_bk.gif';
   c._plla=h+'/translate_a/l';c._ps=b+'/translate_static/css/translateelement.css';
   c._puh='translate.google.com';
   _loadCss(c._ps);_loadJs(b+'/translate_static/js/element/main.js');})();})();
//]]>
</script>
```

> Boom  Now your website will successfully change the language with option appers

[here is image you can see this is result after you follow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk3K1.png)